# Need regular expression to remove /> between two HTML markup tags except img tag

Tags: javascript, html, regex, perl, markup

I need some help crafting a regular expression which removes /> between two HTML markup tags.

```
<!-- The line could look like this -->
<td align=right valign=bottom nowrap><div>January 24, 2013 /></div></td>

<!-- Or this -->
<div>Is this system supported? /></div>

<!-- Even this -->
<span>This is a span tag /></div>

<!-- It could look like any of these but I do not want /> removed -->
<img src="example.com/example.jpg"/></img>
<img src="example.com/example.jpg"/>
<img src="example.com/example.jpg"/></img>
<div id="example"><img src="example.com/example.jpg"/></div>
```

(Yes, I realize the img tag has no closing tag associated with it.  I am dynamically editing a myriad of pages I have not created; it's not my markup.)

Here's the regex I came up with (using perl):

```
s|(<.*?>(?!<img).*?)(\s*/>)(?!</img>)(</.*?>)|$1$3|gi;
```

Is there a better regex that's more efficient or faster?

After regex is applied to the above examples, here are the results:

```
<!-- The line could look like this -->
<td align=right valign=bottom nowrap><div>January 24, 2013></div></td>

<!-- Or this -->
<div>Is this system supported?></div>

<!-- Even this -->
<span>This is a span tag></div>

<!-- It could look like any of these but I do not want /> removed -->
<img src="example.com/example.jpg"/></img>
<img src="example.com/example.jpg"/>
<img src="example.com/example.jpg"/></img>
<div id="example"><img src="example.com/example.jpg"/></div>
```

Comment: Regex is very rarely the right answer for working with HTML. Consider using a DOM parser.

Comment: I agree with you but not an option for what I'm doing, since I have to do this on the back-end.

Comment: back-end has nothing to do with it: PHP has a dom parser built in. ([DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php))

Comment: You're right.  I misspoke.  There a number of edits I'm doing.  The above is just one.  I'm not disagreeing with you that the DOM parser is the way to go, but the above question is just one aspect of a much larger picture of my task. But you're right about the DOM parser.

Comment: That probably makes the DOM parser an even better solution. Pretty much the only good argument against using a parser for this kind of thing is that it can be overkill if you're just making a small tweak to the code. Even then, it's usually a better solution than regex. But if you're doing a lot of editing to the HTML code, then it weighs even more heavily in favour of using a DOM parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A shorter solution would be:

```
s/(<[^>]*>[^<]*)\/>/$1/g
```

It groups an opening tag and the possibly following content, excluding the opening angular bracket - which would indicate another tag. Then it looks for `/>`. If it is found, substition is used to remove it.

**Update:** The question was extended to remove possible whitespace before the `/>`. This can be done by making the `[^<]*` part "lazy" like so:

```
s/(<[^>]*>[^<]*?)\s*\/>/$1/g
```

See for yourself on [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/dY7uW7) (link updated).

Comment: Oh, Wow!  I'm so glad I asked this question.  That site is wonderful.  And your solution is equally great.  I will try it out in practice and  review.  Thank you so much for your contribution!

Comment: Question?  How can I remove the space between he content and the /> ?  In your example, the /> has been removed but the space remains.  I tried adding \s* before /> in your regex expression but it did not work.

Comment: +1 for compact and efficient. I was going to suggest the [exclusion technique](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23589174/match-or-replace-a-pattern-except-in-situations-s1-s2-s3-etc/23589204#23589204) I use all the time, but in this case your answer is faster. :)